# Why Is My MS OneDrive Icon Grey?

Tags: office365, microsoft, microsoft-onedrive

The OneDrive icon in the system tray is grey and not blue, like the OneDrive icon on my work PC. Both are using the same version of Office 365 and OneDrive.

Why?

Comment: You can see your status by hovering your mouse over the icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From
[What do the OneDrive icons mean?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-do-the-onedrive-icons-mean-11143026-8000-44f8-aaa9-67c985aa49b3)

> A grayed-out OneDrive icon in the taskbar means you're not signed in, or OneDrive setup hasn't completed.

If your icon doesn't look like
[image]
find your icon in this link to understand what it means.

Comment: Yes - this is how my icon looks, and No - I'm signed in all right. I can see a history of files being synced, I can edit `settings`. How else can I tell that I'm signed in or not?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think the actual colour of my icon suppose to be white, but it is grey because my desktop notification area is grey.